# Disable Request Journaling, without restarting

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I want to proxy requests and then snapshot them using Wiremock. So I have to have `request-journaling` enabled. But for subsequent runs, after taking the snapshot, I don't really need this functionality, is there a way to switch the config, without having to restart the Wiremock instance. (Note: This is for performance reasons. Also I do know about the max_journal_entries parameter, which is quite useful in this scenario, but I am wondering if I can completely disable them)